# How to specify a cell in parameter in c#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, parameters

I am trying to find a way to specify a cell in a parameter. I am trying to add " X" to the text from my database in a dataGridView and I am using the following code. the problem in this code is that it adds the " X" to the whole column, and I was wondering if there's a way to choose a cell in a parameter as I want to add the " X" to a certain cell.

```
    private void table1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "Data Source = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 0159";
        string Query1 = @"Insert into TopShineDB.Table1 (Timee, CarColorNumber, Interior, Exterior) values(@Timee, @CarColorNumber, @Interior, @Exterior)";
        using (MySqlConnection conn1 = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Query1, conn1))
        {
            conn1.Open();

            command.Parameters.Add("@Timee", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@CarColorNumber", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Interior", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Exterior", MySqlDbType.VarChar);

            try
            {

                foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    command.Parameters["@Timee"].Value = dr.Cells[0].Value;
                    command.Parameters["@CarColorNumber"].Value = dr.Cells[1].Value;
                    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor == Color.GreenYellow)
                    {
                        command.Parameters["@Interior"].Value = dr.Cells[2].Value + " X";
                    }
                    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor == Color.GreenYellow)
                    {
                        command.Parameters["@Exterior"].Value = dr.Cells[3].Value + " X";
                    }

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: If you don't want to append X, add another condition and *don't* append X. You already check for color and change the value to save. Add a different condition that doesn't append X

Comment: I'm sorry I think you misunderstood what I meant. I want to append X but only to a certain cell and not to the whole parameter. The code that I have appends it to the whole column. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Cells have no meaning when talking about query parameters. A parameter has just one value, whatever you assign to it.

Answer (score 1):

firstly as common practice in any programming language I would change:

```
if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor == Color.GreenYellow)
{
    command.Parameters["@Interior"].Value = dr.Cells[2].Value + " X";
}
if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor == Color.GreenYellow)
{
    command.Parameters["@Exterior"].Value = dr.Cells[3].Value + " X";
}
```

to:

```
if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor == Color.GreenYellow)
{
    command.Parameters["@Interior"].Value = dr.Cells[2].Value + " X";
    command.Parameters["@Exterior"].Value = dr.Cells[3].Value + " X";
}
```

as the two if statements are equivalent. Also, what exactly are you using the BackColor of the cells for? Personally if I wanted to achieve adding an X to cell (2,3) for example I would do:

```
command.Parameters["@Interior"].Value = this.dataGridView1[2,3].Value + " X";
command.Parameters["@Exterior"].Value = this.dataGridView1[2,3].Value + " X";
```

instead of iterating through each row and doing multiple conditional statements.

Let me know if this achieves what you want, else I can update for you.

Best of luck!

Comment: This is actually a part of my code. I am giving the user the ability to change the color of the cell. now if the user chooses GreenYellow I want the data in the cell to be followed by the " X" for example if the cell has the text "Mark" and the user chooses the color GreenYellow it will be saved in the database as "Mark X" and if he doesn't it'll be saved into the database normally. I am making this to help me retrieve the color from the database. for example I make an if statement that if the text ends with " X" then set the backcolor of the cell to GreenYellow. thank you for your help.

Comment: the problem with the code that I wrote is that the " X" gets added to the entire column. what I want is to add it to certain cell.

Comment: Oh okay I understand what you're saying now I think... Have you tried adding a further parameter to `command` for Cell, e.g. `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cell", this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell);` ?

Comment: Will this work if the user adds the name in the cell?

Comment: I would hope so... if not then I may not be able to help you